# Referral system web2py how to make?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

Good day, i am making web site and i need to make that user could register, only if  he has a referral link.
Also each user constantly have only 2 referral links, which can changes after registration a new user.
Is there a any ready-made system for web2py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any ready-made system for referral. If you want to search for something, http://www.web2py.com/appliances and https://github.com/mdipierro/web2py-appliances are good places to check.

If you would rather roll your own, I suggest the following steps:

1. Create a table containing an integer or string for a UUID, a boolean for unused/used and a reference to the auth_user table.
2. In your controller for registration read the `request.args[0]` field which is meant to contain a UUID. That would make a referral link look something like *yourdomain*/default/register/*UUID*.
3. Check if the passed UUID is contained in table created in the first step and has not been used yet.
4. If not, give an error message. If yes, register the new user and create two new UUIDs for him (just do `import uuid` and `uuid.uuid4()` and insert into the table created in the first step).
5. Set the state of the referral UUID to used.
6. Show the new user his two referral links on his profile page.

Since the probability of guessing a particular UUID is extremely low (even if you have millions of them), this approach will prevent anybody from registering who does not provide a valid referral link.